# Why can i make same-type requirement in swift with generics? Is there any way?

Tags: swift, generics

Ok so i have some class defined like this:

```
public final class Process<InputType, OutputType, Memory>
```

And i want to make the function available only for case when InputType and 
OutputType are exactly same type.
So i tried like this like this:

```
extension Process where InputType == OutputType { }
```

But this would result in:

> Same-type requirement makes generic parameters `InputType` and
>   `OutputType` equivalent

So then i've gone a bit far and tried to do it like this:

```
func bypass<SameType>() -> Process<SameType, SameType, Memory> where OutputType == InputType {}
```

But this would result in exactly same error.
So the question is why can't i define generics in such way that two generic types would be Equivalent, cause that's exactly what i wanted. I wanted to define function available only for this case, that would fail at compile time if this rule is not followed.

So right now i'm using something like this:

```
public static func bypass<SameType>() -> Process<SameType, SameType, Memory>
```

Which would ultimately fail only at runtime and not even when created but when the concrete class is triggered for action.

Is there any way to define `extension` or `function` for generic parameters of same type that would just not compile(result in compile time error)?

Update: some details of implementations are missed cause would make code unreadable and they are not critical for the context

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In **Swift 4 and later**, you can write:

```
public final class Process<InputType, OutputType, Memory> {
    // ...
}

extension Process where InputType == OutputType {
    func bypass() -> Process<InputType, OutputType, Memory> {
        // ...
    }
}
```

---

**Original answer (Swift 3):**

You can't constraint types on generic classes yet even though [some changes](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0143-conditional-conformances.md) are coming in Swift 4. However, you can constraint types on a protocol. You can make a protocol that only `Process` conforms to like this:

```
protocol ProcessProtocol {
    // I haven't found a way to name these associated type identically to
    // those in the class. If anyone discover a way, please let me know
    associatedtype IT
    associatedtype OT
    associatedtype MT
}

final public class Process<InputType, OutputType, MemoryType>: ProcessProtocol {
    typealias IT = InputType
    typealias OT = OutputType
    typealias MT = MemoryType

    // your code
}

// Note that this is an extension on the protocol, not the class
extension ProcessProtocol where IT == OT {
    func foo() {
        // this function is only available when InputType = OutputType
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this totally solves my problem until Swift 4 comes