# Can I specialize a generic method implementation in Swift?

Tags: swift, generics, swift3

I would like to implement a generic function in two ways, one of them specialized to a specific generic value, but so far I was not able to express this in Swift 3.

My setup is like this:

```
protocol Convertible {

    func convert<T>() -> Converted<T>
}

struct Unconverted: Convertible {

    func convert<T>() -> Converted<T> {
        return Converted<T>()
    }
}

struct Converted<T>: Convertible {

    func convert<T2>() -> Converted<T2> {
        return Converted<T2>()
    }
}
```

What I would like to achieve is to add a special case for `convert()` on `Converted<T>`, for the case where `T2 == T`, so the following behavior is achieved:

```
let unconverted: Convertible = Unconverted()
let converted: Convertible = unconverted.convert() as Converted<String>

// double conversion to same generic type is ok, should ideally return self
let convertedOk = converted.convert() as Converted<String>

// re-conversion to another type is not ok and should fail
let convertedFail = converted.convert() as Converted<Int>
```

I tried the following approaches, but none of them worked out:

```
struct Converted<T> {

    func convert<T2>() -> Converted<T2> {
        fatalError("already converted")
    }

    // error: Same-type requirement makes generic parameters 'T2' and 'T' equivalent
    func convert<T2>() -> Converted<T2> where T2 == T {
        return self
    }
}


struct Converted<T> {

    func convert<T2>() -> Converted<T2> {
        fatalError("already converted")
    }

    // method is never called, even when T2 == T
    func convert() -> Converted<T> {
        return self
    }
}


struct Converted<T> {

    func convert<T2>() -> Converted<T2> {
        // does not call the specialized method, even when T2 == T
        self.internalConvert(type: T2.self)
    }

    private func internalConvert<T2>(type: T2.Type) -> Converted<T2> {
        fatalError("already converted")
    }

    private func internalConvert(type: T.Type) -> Converted<T> {
        return self
    }
}
```

Is there a way to express this?

Comment: How about using associated types?
`protocol Proxy {
    associatedtype dataType
}

struct Converted<T:Proxy> {
    
    func convert<T2>() -> Converted<T2> {
        fatalError("already converted")
    }
    
    // error: Same-type requirement makes generic parameters 'T2' and 'T' equivalent
    func convert<T2:Proxy> () -> Converted<T2>? where T2.dataType == T.dataType {
        return nil
    }
}`

Comment: Thanks @lazy I tried that and unfortunately it has the same issue as my last two attempts (the specialized method is not called)

Comment: This shoudl help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40941566/why-can-i-make-same-type-requirement-in-swift-with-generics-is-there-any-way